# Knockout.js use foreach to display object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this Viewmodel to load the users and their list of Socialgraphs from WCF services. The users appear correct but no socialgraph entry appears. I have checked the service and json returned and all seems ok.

Should I change my Models to sth different or is it the way I'm loading stuff in the ViewModel? thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var viewModel = {

    users: ko.observableArray([]),              

    loadUsers: function () {
        OData.read("Service_UserProfile/", function (data) {

            viewModel.users.removeAll();
            $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {                    
                var socialgraphs = viewModel.loadSocialGraph();
                var user = new UserProfileModel(item, socialgraphs);                   
                viewModel.users.push(user);                   
            });
        });
    },

    loadSocialGraph: function () {

        var result = new Array();
        // user id will be loaded dynamically in later steps
        OData.read("/Service_UserProfile(1)/Socialgraph/", function (data) {

            $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {                   
                result.push(new SocialGraph(item));                    
           });
        });        
        return result;
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
viewModel.loadUsers();
```

});

The Model

```
function UserProfileModel(item,socialgraphs) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(item.Id),
    this.Nickname = ko.observable(item.Nickname),
    this.socialgraphs = ko.observableArray(socialgraphs)
};

function SocialGraph(item) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(item.Id),
    this.StartTime = ko.observable(item.StartTime),
    this.Latitude = ko.observable(item.Latitude),
    this.Longitude = ko.observable(item.Longitude)
};
```

The View

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Nickname
            </th>
            <th>Social Graph
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: users">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Nickname"></td>
            <td>
                <ul data-bind="foreach: socialgraphs">
                    <li data-bind="text: Id"></li>
                    <li data-bind="dateString: StartTime"></li>
                    <li data-bind="text: Latitude"></li>
                    <li data-bind="text: Longitude"></li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in the console (using Firebug under Firefox or Chrome Dev Tools under Chrome)?

Comment: No binding errors, and the socialgraphs array is populated when I console.log it

Comment: when initialising your socialgraphs observablearray, try looping through and adding them individually instead of all together.  might be something wrong there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change:

```
loadSocialGraph: function () {

    var result = ko.observableArray();
    // user id will be loaded dynamically in later steps
    OData.read("/Service_UserProfile(1)/Socialgraph/", function (data) {

        $.each(data.results, function (index, item) {                   
            result.push(new SocialGraph(item));                    
       });
    });        
    return result;
}
```

and

```
function UserProfileModel(item,socialgraphs) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(item.Id),
    this.Nickname = ko.observable(item.Nickname),
    this.socialgraphs = socialgraphs
};
```

Why:
At the line `this.socialgraphs = ko.observableArray(socialgraphs)`
socialgraphs in the right part is []. Only after some time interval it
will be filled with values. And because of it is not observable array,
knockout won't notice that some items were pushed in it. I.e. it will stay empty.